# Remove duplicates from a list object containing a list while merging the containing list

Tags: java, list, collections, duplicates

```
I hava a POJO Classes:
    class Response {
        private List<Transmission> transmission;
    }
    class Transmission {
        private String transmission_id;
        private String transmission_name;
        private String transmission_type;
        private List<Page> page;
    }
    class Page {
        private String page_id;
        private String page_no;
        private String page_type;
    }
```

I have response List returned from Database as:

```
transmission_id     transmission_name  transmission_type    page_id page_no         page_loaction


000066              XXX                     AAA                 1           1                 cdrive                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
000066              XXX                     AAA                 2           2                 cddfdrive                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
000066              XXX                     AAA                 3           3                 asdecdrive

000067              YYY                     BBB                 1           1                 dDrive                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
000067              YYY                     BBB                 2           2                 dDadecrive                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
000067              YYY                     BBB                 3           3                 dqwdDrive
```

I want to return Responseclass returned by modifying removing the duplicate elements from transmission list meaning each transmission_id,transmission_name,transmission_type 
I am trying to achieve is to get the following out put by taking only unique elements of transmission

```
Ex:  <Transmission>
         <transmission_id>000066 </transmission_id>
         < transmission_name> XXX </transmission_name>
         < transmission_type> AAA </transmission_type>
         <Page>
            < page_id>1</ page_id>
            <page_no>1</page_no>
            <page_loaction>cdrive</page_loaction>
         </Page>
         <Page>
            < page_id>2</ page_id>
            <page_no>2</page_no>
            <page_loaction>cdrive</page_loaction>
         </Page>
         <Page>
            < page_id>3</ page_id>
            <page_no>3</page_no>
            <page_loaction>cdrive</page_loaction>
         </Page>
         </Transmission>
          <Transmission>
         <transmission_id>000067 </transmission_id>
         < transmission_name> YYY </transmission_name>
         < transmission_type> BBB </transmission_type>
         <Page>
            < page_id>1</ page_id>
            <page_no>2</page_no>
            <page_loaction> dDrive</page_loaction>
         </Page>
         <Page>
            < page_id>2</ page_id>
            <page_no>2</page_no>
            <page_loaction> dDrive</page_loaction>
         </Page>
         <Page>
            < page_id>3</ page_id>
            <page_no>3</page_no>
            <page_loaction>dDrive/page_loaction>
         </Page>
         </Transmission>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!! You mean your unique elements are composed of `transmission_id, transmission_name, transmission_type`?

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? At least brute force approach? Go over your list and delete all duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Override `equals` and `hashcode` on `Transmission`. Add all results to `Set<Transmission>` then to list the set.

*Edit

Add a function to `Response` `addTransmission` where  you check if  you already have a transmission and add a page to that or create a new one with that page.

You may want to be using ORM like hibernate to handle the mapping for you

Comment: but transmission has another list page which isnt duplicate so it is not giving the result I want